# how to glue datasource and filters in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to implement server-side filtering for ag-grid

on grid ready event I configure datasource object:

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    var that = this;
    params.api.setDatasource({
      getRows(params) {
        that._fetchData(data => params.successCallback(data));
      }
    });
  }
```

the datasource is called and data gets displayed. but when I change filtering -- nothing happens. here is a sandbox to demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wkop8pj6kl (https://gist.github.com/evgeny-t/90ef8e37fe747549a1d8203ef806df9e)

is it possible to do within the community version? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, add `enableServerSideFilter` flag to `AgGridReact`

You can also use `enableServerSideSorting` flag if required.

This thread helped me (https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2237)